# Woocommerce order fail issue after successful payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, paytm

I am having a Woocommerce store, in which PayTM payment gateway is integrated using plugin for payments.

I am facing an issue:
Sometimes order got failed on woocommerce and show error: "It seems some issue in server to server communication. Kindly connect with administrator."

But when I check on PayTM dashboard, the payment status is successful.

This happens with 30-40 percentage of total orders.

I found this in error logs:
`This was the full error:

`[30-May-2019 17:48:35 UTC] WordPress database error Unknown column 'Ok' in 'where clause' for query delete from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_service_Riders of Tumakuru_%range"
                                                         and meta_value = Ok and post_id = 4185 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->parse_request, do_action_ref_array, WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_API->handle_api_requests, do_action('woocommerce_api_wc_paytm'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_paytm->check_paytm_response, WC_paytm->txn_failure, WC_Order->update_status, WC_Order->save, WC_Order->status_transition, do_action('woocommerce_order_status_failed'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, YITH_Tickets_Premium->remove_order_ticket, yith_wcevti_remove_service_sold``

Any Help will be appreciable.

Comment: Did you check server log ?

Comment: @Aki Yes I found this:

`WP->main, WP->parse_request, do_action_ref_array, WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_API->handle_api_requests, do_action('woocommerce_api_wc_paytm'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_paytm->check_paytm_response, WC_paytm->txn_failure, WC_Order->update_status, WC_Order->save, WC_Order->status_transition, do_action('woocommerce_order_status_failed')`

Comment: Then put that error in question then anyone of us can help you

Comment: ok thanks, I Updated the question.

Comment: In which file you found the error?

Comment: error_log in the main directory of wordpress.

Comment: When ever you get the error in error.log file it will let you know which file is throwing the error

Comment: Full error is updated in question, please check.